# How to find out the Hybris version of a server?

Tags: version, sap-commerce-cloud

Is there any specific way of finding out the Hybris version of a server.

I know that the hybris version appears in logs during server startup but I was wondering if it can be found somewhere in hac or backoffice. That way I will be able lookup the version deployed on a specific test machine.

I also know about the hac foot note which opens the popup mentioning **the OS**, the **number of CPUs**, and the **version**. But for older versions of Hybris the version is not included.

Comment: did you check the `HMC` interface footer ?

Comment: Yes, this should be working for older versions of Hybris

Answer (score 7):

You can check the hybris version by navigating to **hybris\bin\platform** and opening the file named **build.number**. It should have content similar to the below content :

```
#Ant properties
#Tue Dec 12 15:56:57 CET 2017
builddate=20171212 1548
releasedate=20171212 1548
vendor=hybris
version=6.5.0.4
version.api=6.5.0
```

Answer (score 5):

You can see the platform version from hac -> Platform -> Configuration and look for the **build.version** property. The value should be the hybris version, and I think that still work for 5.x versions.

Or you can download some console logs to check for the startup version (using the uptime as a guide for what to download) also via hac -> Platform -> Support

Comment: the **build.version** is not present for Hybris 5.5.1.0 for example. I saw that the hybris 6.2 has it. Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 4):

Also, when the Hybris server starts, you can check the version. It would look something like this-

Starting up hybris server

```
Configuration:

Cluster:     disabled
Tenant:      master
Mode:        development
OS:          Mac OS X 10.13.6, x86_64
Database:    Pool: hybris - hsqldb, table prefix: 
             SA - jdbc:hsqldb:file:/Users/abcd/Hybris/hybris/data/hsqldb/mydb;shutdown=true;hsqldb.tx=MVCC
Platform:    6.6.0.4
Java:        Oracle Corporation
             Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, 1.8.0_191-b12
             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
VM Locale:   language=en,country=US,region=null
Cache:       RegionCache is not yet initialized. [de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter]
Server type: tomcat
```

Answer (score 3):

You can go to hac > Platform > Configuration and search for version.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are two more options that can be used:

1. "ant -p" should render also the Hybris Version
2. Open  hybris/data/build.number